# Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox() маска русские буквы

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo

Необходимо создать маску ввода только для русских символов + пробел + точка + запятая. Никак не пойму как указать что именно русские буквы.

```
@Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("FIO").Mask(
```

Comment: Попробуйте через рулы: `@Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Fio").Rules(rules => rules.Add('~', @"\u0400-\u04FF")).Mask("~")` это только для русских сымловов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вариант через KendoValidator

```
rules: {
            Name: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[id=Name]")) {
                    if ($("#Name").val() != "" && (/^[а-яА-Я]+$/).test($("#Name").val()))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```